# The package installation version is not applied by docker

Tags: docker, typeorm

I'm trying to make nestjs a docker image.
In the process, I am not getting the dockerfile command order to work.

```js
#work
FROM node:16 as development

ARG NODE_ENV=local
ENV NODE_ENV=local
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

RUN yarn install --only=development

RUN yarn build

#not work

FROM node:16 as development

ARG NODE_ENV=local
ENV NODE_ENV=local
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN yarn build
```

Many blogs say that the bottom is more efficient, but in my case it doesn't work.

The reason it doesn't work is that I'm using `typeorm` version `0.2.x`,

the command below always installs the typeorm `0.3.x` version.

I write "typeorm": "^0.2.32" in the package.json, but I get the same result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How are you running the container?  How are you validating the installed package version?  (One popular setup for Node overrides the image's `node_modules` directory with an anonymous volume, and if you do this then changes in the Dockerfile won't have an effect.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not verifying, I thought it was supposed to install based on the contents of the pacakage.json like normal nestjs, but that's not it?